# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageSize' of undefined

Tags: json, slickgrid

Iam trying to apply paging to slickgrid and it shows an error in slick.pager.js as title in console and my code is

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON('http://localhost:50305/Service1.svc/json/EmployeeDetails', function (data) {

        dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
        dataView.setItems(data, "EmpId");
        dataView.setPagingOptions({ pageSize: 4 });
        grid = new Slick.Grid("#teamGrid", dataView.rows, columns, options);
        var pager = new Slick.Controls.Pager(dataView, grid, $("#pager"));

 dataView.onPagingInfoChanged.subscribe(function (e, pagingInfo) {
            alert("hi");
            var isLastPage = pagingInfo.pageNum == pagingInfo.totalPages - 1;
            var enableAddRow = isLastPage || pagingInfo.pageSize == 0;
            var options = grid.getOptions();

            if (options.enableAddRow != enableAddRow) {
                grid.setOptions({ enableAddRow: enableAddRow });
            }
        });

        dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (args) {
            grid.updateRowCount();
            grid.render();
        });
```

Comment: If this still matters, I think I get the problem now. You're creating a new dataview inside the callback function. That's going to cause problems. You should follow the remotemodel example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataView.beginUpdate();
dataView.setItems(data, "EmpId");
dataView.endUpdate();

dataView.setPagingOptions({ pageSize: 4 });
grid = new Slick.Grid("#teamGrid", dataView, columns, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't really even make sense.
The line

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON('http://localhost:50305/Service1.svc/json/EmployeeDetails', function (data) {
```

is not well formed. There should be a function body and a closing brace.
The variable jqxhr is not used anywhere. Why does this line even exist ?

Answer (score 0):

```
`pagesize=10`
let pagesizealt
 if(!this.paginator){
  pagesizealt=this.pagesize.toString()
   }
    else{
      pagesizealt=this.paginator.pageSize
}`
```

u have to check for paginator to initialize after initializtion provide the value of pageSize